# How to make footer fit with all screens

Tags: html, css

**I designed a web page
Everything good off until I got to the end
How can I make items in the middle when the screen is long.
but here All items go to the left.
The picture and the code are below**

[image]

Comment: There is no code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try putting all of the elements into a div. after that style the div as such: 
'''

```
div {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

'''